# I/O Completion Ports vs. RegisterWaitForSingleObject?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, file-io, asynchronous, io-completion-ports

What's the difference between using I/O completion ports, versus just using [`RegisterWaitForSingleObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685061.aspx) to have a thread pool thread wait for I/O to complete?

Is one of them faster, and if so, why?

Comment: "Faster" is a term relative to the task at hand. What is it you're planning on doing (or actually doing)? These two technologies are markedly different, so knowing what you're trying to accomplish will be significant in which is a better fit to your problem.

Comment: @WhozCraig: I'm doing a bunch of large disk reads and processing data as it comes; the bottleneck is I/O so the goal is to achieve maximum throughput (data from different disks would be read in parallel, while data from the same disk would be read serially). I feel like both of them would work for my design, I just don't know which one to use.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IOCP's are generally the fastest performing IO turn-around mechanism you will find for one reason above all else: blocking detection.

The simple example of this is a server that is responsible for serving up files from a disk. An IOCP is generally made up of three primary things:

1. The pool of N threads for servicing the IOCP requests.
2. A limit of M threads (M is always < N) the tells the IOCP how many *concurrent, non-blocked* threads to allow.
3. A completion-status loop that all threads run on.

The difference between N and M in this is *very* important. The general philosophy is to configure M to be the number of cores on the machine, and N to be larger. How much larger depends on the amount of time your worker threads spend in a blocked-state. If you're reading disk files, your threads will be bound to the speed of the disk IO channel. When you make that call to `ReadFile()` you've just introduced a blocking call. If M == N, then as soon as you hit all threads reading disk files, you're utterly stalled, with all threads on the disk IO channel.

But what if there was a way for some fancy scheduler to "know" that this thread is (a) participating in an IOCP thread pool, and (b) just stalled because it issued an API call that will be time consuming? What if, when that happens, that fancy scheduler could temporarily "move" that thread into a special "running-but-stalled" group, and then "release" an extra thread that has volunteered to work while there are threads stalled?

That is *exactly* what IOCP brings. When N is *greater* than M, The IOCP will put the thread that just issued the stall into a special running-but-stalled state, and then temporarily "borrow" an additional thread from your pool of N. It will continue to do this until the N pool is exhausted, or threads that were stalled begin returning from their blocking requests.

So under that light, an IOCP configured to have, say 8 threads concurrently running on an 8-core machine could actually have a few hundred threads in the real pool. Only 8 will ever be "allowed" to be concurrently running in non-blocked state, though you may pop over that temporarily when blocked threads return from their blocks and you already have borrowed threads servicing additional requests.

Finally, though not as important for your cause, it is still important: An IOCP thread will NOT block, nor context switch, if there is pending work on the queue when it finishes its current work and issues its next `GetQueueCompletionStatus()` call. If there is work waiting, it will pick it up and continue executing with no mandated preemption. Of course the OS scheduler may preempt anyway, but only as part of the general scheduler; not because of the specific call to `GetQueueCompletionStatus()`. The lone exception to this is if there are already over M threads running and non-blocked. In that case, `GetQueueCompletionStatus()` will block the calling thread until it is needed again for slack-work when enough threads once-again become blocked.

The description you gave indicates you will be heavily disk-io-bound. For absolute performance-critical io-server architectures, it is near-impossible to beat the benefits of IOCP, *especially* the OS-level block-detection that allows the scheduler to know it can temporarily release extra threads from your master-pool to keep things pumping while other threads are stalled.

You simply cannot replicate that specific feature of IOCPs using Windows thread pools. If all of your threads were number crunchers with little or no IO, I would say thread-pools would be a better fit, but your specificity of disk-IO tells me you should be using an IOCP instead.

Comment: One addition to this is that IOCPs use unfair scheduling (threads that are asleep tend to stay asleep, threads that are running tend to stay in memory), which means you can make N pretty much as huge as you like without having to worry about thrashing the scheduler and memory manager.

Comment: I just realized that `QueueUserWorkItem`'s documentation for `WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT` says that "the callback function is queued to a thread that uses I/O completion ports", whereas `RegisterWaitForSingleObject`'s documentation for the same flag doesn't include that sentence. Do you know if `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` uses IOCP for `WT_EXECUTEDEFAULT` too or not? If it does, is it just as efficient for me to use `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` then? (According to WINE they both use `RtlQueueWorkItem`, so it's likely they would be the same...)

Comment: @Mehrdad I don't believe so, but [BindIoCompletionCallback()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363484(v=vs.85).aspx) does (the name is somewhat a dead give-away). There is a significant warning concerning making sure you check the result of your IO request before setting up a bind. It *must* have returned ERROR_IO_PENDING or you'll be issuing a callback request that will never come.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Ooh, thanks for the heads-up. And I just did a quick disassembly of `RtlRegisterWait` and found that it uses `NtQueueApcThread` on the thread-pool thread instead of IOCP, at least on Windows XP. :) Thanks!

Comment: @WhozCraig: Interestingly, I just found that APC's don't seem to perform a context switch when it isn't necessary, either: http://pastebin.com/NdXip9kb It's not foolproof of course but it's reasonably convincing.

Comment: ... oh yeah but the fact that they use APCs means that the thread is determined at queuing time, not at dequeuing time. I guess IOCP beats them hands-down then!

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm not surprised at all. Designing an IOCP-based system is a little different than traditional alterable configurations, but it sounds like you're definitely apt to handle it. I use them for many things, including seemingly simple things like regular single-process work-queues. They're incredibly flexible, and as I drove home in my answer, that low-level block-detection is simply the cats pajamas. I wish you good times in programming one, and suggest you play around with test models for awhile first. You learn a lot with hands-on IOCP.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Haha yeah they seem awesome just for general producer/consumer queues! and thanks! :)

Comment: @WhozCraig, surely in your example above you'd just use overlapped reads for your file reads and all your blocking goes away??

Comment: @LenHolgate Absolutely, Len, especially if they were files larger than a system page. In that case I would likely do exactly as you described, and thank you for pointing it out. Much apprec.